# How to match array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

Friends please help me with this as I am new to angular and typescript

```
export class TopPage implements OnInit {
  //city = localStorage.getItem('city');
  city = 'bangalore';
  areas_array = {
    "bangalore": ['one', 'two'],
    "chennai": ['four', 'five'],
    "hyderabad": ['six', 'seven']
  };

  area;
}

if (city === areas_array) {
  //areas that matches the city
}
```

I want to get the array within areas_array that matches the city. and is it right way to format areas_array

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. What are you trying to do? What is `areas_array`?

Comment: Can you please add more details? Also, why does `areas` is an array with 1 object?

Comment: If you want to select that `bangalore` area, you can do this: `this.area = this.areas[0][city]` (not sure why do you have that dictionary wrapped in array...)

Comment: Someone approved Shiv's edit. I'm not sure if that's what OP meant

Comment: @Eddie The OP did, so it seems to be what they meant.

Comment: @Eddie i think he is searching `city` in `areas_array` array and assign in `area`. if its like this then suggested solution would be `this.area = this.areas_array[0][this.city]`

Comment: I hope OP noticed the change @str.

Comment: Maybe you are right @ShivKumarBaghel, but I personally believe that we should not edit the post (especially the code part) on what *we personally* think the OP is trying to say. That is just me. :)

Comment: Not "just you" :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop and check with key:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  areas_array = {
    "bangalore": ['one', 'two'],
    "chennai": ['four', 'five'],
    "hyderabad": ['six', 'seven']
  };


  constructor() {
    let serchCity = 'bangalore';
    for (let key in this.areas_array) {
      if (key === serchCity) {
        console.log(this.areas_array[serchCity]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Refer:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjndzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(areas_array).filter(key=> key===city).map(match=> areas_array[match]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for .. in` to iterate the array keys or values.

```
city = 'bangalore';
areas_array = {
  "bangalore": ['one', 'two'],
  "chennai": ['four', 'five'],
  "hyderabad": ['six', 'seven']
};

for (let key in areas_array) {
  if (key === city) { 
    // logic
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well.